# SVN remove files from the to-be-committed list

Tags: svn, commit

I had set up ignore rules on my bin / object folders for my project.  I then tried to do an add on all the other files with svn add * .  It seemed as if the ignore only applies to the svn status command so all my bin and object folder contents showed up.  Now I have not done a commit on the list, but when I do an svn status I see all those nasty files ready to go when I send that command.  Is there a way to remove them from that list or clear that list completely? Also, what is that list called?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
svn revert bin
```

Would remove the bin directory from being added at the next commit.

Or if you would like to recursively revert (sometimes useful)

```
svn revert -R bin
```

Answer (score 5):

You should revert the added files that you don't want committed.

To ignore those folders in the future, add them to the svn:ignore list of the **parent folder**.  Read all about ignoring unversioned items [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you have TortoiseSVN installed, you can use the explorer right-click menu context: TortoiseSVN, Unadd.

Note: You'll only see unadd if, like in your case, you've tagged folder/file to be added.

Comment: If the folder to undo the add does not exist, (i.e from a svn rename failure)  simply create a blank folder with the name. Then that folder will have Undo Add on right-click menu context, and it will also undo any recursive folders.